# Parnotes: How to set width of parnote to same width as tabular?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabularx, width, textwidth, parnotes

Consider the following **Minimum Working Example (MWE)**:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,parnotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{lcc}
            \parnoteclear
            c & c & c\parnote{This is a veeeeeeeery looooooooooooooooooong parnote and too wide}\\\hline
        \end{tabularx}
        \parnotes
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Description of the issue:**

As you can see, the `parnote` is much wider than the table itself. How can I adjust the width of the `parnote` to the same width as the `table`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `threeparttable` package instead:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
        \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{lcc}
            c & c & c\tnote{1} \\\hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[1] {This is a very very very long table note and automatically as wide as the table}
    \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

If you want to stay with `parnotes`, you could use a `parbox` as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,parnotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{lcc}
            \parnoteclear
            c & c & c\parnote{This is a very very very very very very very very long parnote and too wide}\\\hline
        \end{tabularx}

        \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\parnotes}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

For your actual table you might want to keep in mind to use at least one `X` type column in a `tabularx` environment.